# Using get() to retrieve functions from a package that is not loaded

Tags: r

I can use `get` to access functions, like so:

```r
get("sum")
# function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

If I want to get a function from a package, I can load the package and then get the function:

```r
library(data.table)
get("uniqueN")

# function (x, by = if (is.list(x)) seq_along(x) else NULL, na.rm = FALSE) 
# {
#   if (is.null(x)) 
#     return(0L)
#   if (!is.atomic(x) && !is.data.frame(x)) 
#     stop("x must be an atomic vector or data.frames/data.tables")
#   if (is.atomic(x)) {
#     if (is.logical(x)) 
#       return(.Call(CuniqueNlogical, x, na.rm = na.rm))
#     x = as_list(x)
#   }
#   o = forderv(x, by = by, retGrp = TRUE, na.last = if (!na.rm) 
#     FALSE
#     else NA)
#   starts = attr(o, "starts", exact = TRUE)
#   if (!na.rm) {
#     length(starts)
#   }
#   else {
#     sum((if (length(o)) o[starts] else starts) != 0L)
#   }
# }
# <bytecode: 0x5559622e2f60>
#   <environment: namespace:data.table>
```

Now, say I want to do this *without* loading the package. My initial thought was,

```r
get("data.table::uniqueN")
# Error in get("data.table::uniqueN") : 
#   object 'data.table::uniqueN' not found
```

Clearly, that doesn't work. Within `get`, I can specify the environment where to look for the object (i.e., with the `envir` parameter), but as the package is not loaded presumably there *isn't* a package environment yet.

---

**Question**: How do I `get` a function from a package that isn't loaded?

Comment: Why do you need to use `get` , why not just `data.table::uniqueN`?

Comment: Because the function(s) I wish to call are dynamic. Say I want the function name to be passed as an argument to a script, for example. The user would specify the function as a string and then I'd need to pull that function.

Comment: @Lyngbakr `:::` and `::` are functions that can take on strings, so surrounding them with backticks and passing strings should work :::("data.table", "uniqueN") should work. Forgot how to escape format backticks in markdown

Comment: @DonaldSeinen That's the solution! Could you put it as an answer so I can close the question, please?

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick! Very helpful to know `get` won't work with unloaded packages.

When I try `eval("data.table::uniqueN")` I just get `"data.table::uniqueN"` returned as a string. Am I doing something daft?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the parse step: `eval(str2expression("data.table::uniqueN"))`

Comment: @Lyngbakr There are probably better approaches that cover more edge cases, for example what should happen if users are after S3 stuff like `base::t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` has an `envir` argument, and you can obtain the namespace of a package via `getNamespace` without attaching it to the search path, so one option is:

```r
get("uniqueN", envir = getNamespace('data.table'))
#> function (x, by = if (is.list(x)) seq_along(x) else NULL, na.rm = FALSE) 
#> {
#>     if (is.null(x)) 
#>         return(0L)
#>     if (!is.atomic(x) && !is.data.frame(x)) 
#>         stop("x must be an atomic vector or data.frames/data.tables")
#>     if (is.atomic(x)) {
#>         if (is.logical(x)) 
#>             return(.Call(CuniqueNlogical, x, na.rm = na.rm))
#>         x = as_list(x)
#>     }
#>     o = forderv(x, by = by, retGrp = TRUE, na.last = if (!na.rm) 
#>         FALSE
#>     else NA)
#>     starts = attr(o, "starts", exact = TRUE)
#>     if (!na.rm) {
#>         length(starts)
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         sum((if (length(o)) o[starts] else starts) != 0L)
#>     }
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000001c545c5e208>
#> <environment: namespace:data.table>
```